# output private ip of VM in azure ARM

Tags: azure, automation, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I am spinning up more than one Azure VM using copyindex() in ARM template. Here is the resource I am using :

```
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'),copyIndex(1))]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmInstancesClientNode')]"
    },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'),copyindex(1))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'),copyindex(1),'-nic')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSizeClientNode')]"
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "computername": "[concat(parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'), copyIndex(1))]",
      "adminUsername": "[parameters('username')]",
      "adminPassword": "[parameters('password')]"
    },
    "storageProfile": {
      "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
        "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
        "sku": "[variables('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
        "version": "latest"
      },
      "osDisk": {
        "name": "osdisk1",
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountName'),copyindex(1),'.blob.core.windows.net/',variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'),'/',parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'),copyIndex(1),'-osdisk1.vhd')]"
        },
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "createOption": "FromImage"
      },
      "dataDisks": [
        {
          "name": "datadisk1",
          "diskSizeGB": "10",
          "lun": 0,
          "vhd": {
            "uri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'),copyindex(1)), variables('apiVersion')).primaryEndpoints.blob, variables('vmDataContainerName'),'/',parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'),copyIndex(1),'-',variables('dataDisk1VhdName'),'.vhd')]"
          },
          "createOption": "Empty"
        }
      ]
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat(parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'),copyindex(1),'-nic'))]"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

I tried something like this, which isn't working

```
"outputs": {
  "privateIP": {
    "value": "[reference(concat(parameters('vmDnsPrefixClientNode'),copyindex(1),'-nic'),providers('Microsoft.Network', 'privateIPAddresses').apiVersions[0]).dnsSettings.fqdn]",
    "type": "string",
    "copy": {
        "name": "vmNic",
        "count": "[parameters('vmInstancesClientNode')]"
    }
  }
}
```

anyone knows how to get private IP or internal FQDN in output ?

Answer (score 4):

I have used the following code in my template to get the private ip address from network interface.

```
"outputs":{
    "networkInterface":{
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName')),'2016-09-01')]",
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

Once you get the output, then you can find the IP address at

> outputs.networkInterface.value.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress

and dns suffix at

> outputs.networkInterface.value.dnsSettings.internalDomainNameSuffix